# Weird issue related to same-origin policy

Tags: javascript

```
var w;

function a() {
    w = window.open('http://www.w.net/x', "asdasd");
    w.document.write("XXX");
    window.setTimeout(b,1000);
}

function b() {
    w.location="http://www.w.net/y";
    w.document.write("YYY");
}

a();
```

I can see XXX written on the new window but not YYY. Why this code doesn't work? How can I make this work?

EDIT: I want XXX to be written on w.net/x and YYY to be written on w.net/y

Comment: Is there a particular url you're actually going to? www.w.net isn't a real domain.

Comment: When I run this code 1) a window opens as a blank target showing XXX, 2) that window changes locations to http://www.w.net/y which does not load because it has just done a GET request so 3) I see an error and not YYY

Comment: Yes, assume those are working URLs, I want YYY is to be written on the new window. I tried many ways but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the console error in FireBug:

> Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'
>
> w.document.write("XXX");

Writing something to the document after calling function b updates the page:

```
function a() {
    w = window.open('http://www.ozzypod.com/about', "asdasd");
    w.document.write("XXX");
    window.setTimeout(b,1000);
    w.document.write(""); // output: XXXYYY
}
```